# Python - Django Models - One Model different Tables to store value

Tags: python, django, orm, model

Can someone help me in Python Django models to create dynamic table name based on value received from the post request for same model i.e one model for different table and each table has a unique name so it doesn't overlap and therefore value in these table can be saved accordingly??

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: Because i will get lots of different value based on which i need to create a separate table in mysql using models orm because each value has long list of values associated to it which is fetched from other tables! Using this table i need to synchronize with dbsqlite present in android tablets ....

Comment: Can't it be a column on one table? Then you simply go from there

Comment: I am picking values from 4 different table and storing in a new table for temporary use and after the work is done i would delete or keep the same table... the table can be used again if requested on other day.. Basically making the content available in remote place to handle the process of work by syncing the data so that other tablet knows the status of work done for each individual.. A bit complex system ... So can you help me out creating tables dynamically based on the name requested via post request with the same model ?? I.e same model with different table name and values stored accdly